# How to use VSCode keyboard shortcuts with a Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm running VSCode for Golang development on my Macbook.  If I right click on a method I can "Go To Definition", but it also says that I can use the keyboard shortcut of `F12` to accomplish the same thing.  The problem is that there is no `F12` key on my macbook.  I have an external keyboard that appears to be trying to double use the "Increase volume" button as a `F12` key, but even when I try using that it doesn't work.

What is the proper keyboard shortcut for "Go To Definition" (or any shortcut that uses the function keys) when you are using a Mac?

Answer (score 13):

A few options:

- Hold the `fn` key and then press `f12` (if your keyboard has an `fn` key)
- [Change the VS Code keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)
- Change your mac to use normal function keys: `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Function Keys ->  Use F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys`

Answer (score 1):

refer to the below Visual Studio Code URL
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

For Macbook

Press COMMAND (i.e. ⌘) symbol and hover over a symbol for the preview of the definition.

You can also jump to the definition by with COMMAND button (i.e. ⌘) + Click
or 
press COMMAND + OPTION + Click to open the definition to the side.